# Tuning mercurial server and identifying bottleneck

Tags: mercurial

I have a very large mercurial repo that takes hours for an initial clone. Clone is being done over https, via scmmanager. I would like to try and get this down to minutes, if possible.

My mercurial repo is running on a server with 24 cores, the load is around 2 while doing a clone from my workstation. I'm wondering how I can tune mercurial on the server to use more cores perhaps. iowait is at 0. Network traffic is low on the server, iftop shows 5Mb/s TX, and I have gigabit ethernet. 4 gigs of ram are being used out of 64 gigs total, and 24 gigs are used for disk cache and 1.5 gigs for buffers.

On my workstation, I have tried renicing hg to -5. Load is around 0.5. My workstation has 8 cores. My workstation has gigabit ethernet also, and seeing minimal traffic also, around 2 Mb/s RX. iowait is also zero on my workstation.

OS for mercurial server is CentOS 6. OS for workstation is Debian jessie. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: tried doing a clone over ssh as well as a local non-hardlinked uncompressed clone. Both take a very long time. (Hours) Repo size is 8 gigs. Unsure how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

The clone itself is very low complexity operation for Mercurial.  Suspect scmmanager.  Try cloning direct from the filesytem using a ssh:// URL and load should be just about zilch.

Also try disabling compression on the clone with `--uncompressed`.  If it helps hgweb makes that settable on the server side.

Comment: How do I determine the user name for the ssh clone?

Comment: It's determined by the server's operating system.  It's probably the username that owns the files for the hg repository on disk.  Going in via ssh is about halfway between "hgweb" and "direct file access" w/r/t to "weight".  My guess is any bottleneck is scmmanager, but going in via ssh should confirm that.

Answer (score 0):

What is the total size of your repositories?

The suggestions Ry4an makes, should indeed resolve your issue. If they don't,  you could also create a bundle and transfer that for the initial clone. See `hg help bundle` for details.
Basically: this creates a single file containing revisions (in your case, you'll want to use '--all') to make sure it contains the entire repository). You can then use wget or any other command to download the file (which should be much faster than 5 Mbps).

Comment: Total size of repo is 8 gigs. Local unhardlinked clone took about 4-5 hours, so it looks like the issue is that hg is not multithreaded for a clone operation.

Comment: I still wouldn't expect this to take so long. Perhaps you can file a bug for this: http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/BugTracker